# ¿Por qué utilizamos variables de referencia para modificar los atributos de clase con métodos (setters y getters) en c++?

Tags: c++, clase, paso-por-referencia, objeto

Vengo del oscuro inframundo de Java, y, queriendo aprender un poco de C++, me he dado de bruces con el dilema entre *pointers* y *references*. Esto sobre todo es un problema a la hora de manejar objetos en clases como la descrita aquí:

```
class A{
    public:
        int some_int;
};

class B{
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        void SetA(A& value){
            a = value;
        }
        A& GetA(){
            return a;
        }
};

int main(){
    B b;
    A a;
    a.some_int = 2;
    b.SetA(a);
    cout << b.GetA().some_int;
}
```

Para el *setter* y el *getter* se utilizan las referencias de variable. Mi pregunta como nativo de Java y principiante en esto de lo serio es: ¿por qué?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El caso del *setter*:

```
void SetA(A& value){ a = value; }
```

Si el objeto lo pasases por valor el programa tendría que hacer una copia temporal del mismo mientras que al pasarlo como referencia te ahorras dicha copia.

Dado que una referencia es similar a un puntero (ambos permiten modificar la variable original) suele ser costumbre que el *setter* reciba el argumento como referencia constante... Así garantizamos que el objeto no va a ser modificado dentro de la función:

```
void SetA(A const& value){ a = value; }
```

El caso del *getter*:

```
A& GetA(){ return a; }
```

Este caso es más delicado. Al devolver una referencia estás exponiendo la variable propia del objeto, lo que puede ser peligroso:

```
B b;
A& a = b.GetA();
a.some_int = -1; // es -1 un valor valido??
```

Lo que se suele hacer es devolver una copia del objeto para prevenir precisamente este tipo de problemas.

Una alternativa que se puede apreciar, por ejemplo, en la STL es ofrecer dos versiones del *getter*: la habitual que devuelve una copia y una segunda pensada para cuando el objeto es constante que devuelve una referencia constante. Como dicho así parece complicado lo vemos mejor con un ejemplo:

```
 // Versión normal
A GetA(){ return a; }

// Versión para el objeto constante
const A& GetA() const { return a; }
```

La principal ventaja de esta solución estriba en que al utilizar el objeto en su formato constante podemos ofrecer una referencia puesto que tenemos la *seguridad* de que la variable miembro no se va a ver modificada:

```
const B b;
A& a = b.GetA(); // error, la referencia debe ser constante
const A& a = b.GetA();
a.some_int = -1; // error, la referencia es constante
```

Por supuesto si un *getter* nos devuelve una referencia podemos optar por hacer una copia si ello nos conviene:

```
const B b;
A a = b.GetA(); // hacemos una copia de A
a.some_int = -1; nuestra copia no es constante
```

Comment: Entiendo... Entonces, si quiero cambiar el atributo `a` en una versión externa, como atributo público que es, bastaría con `A GetA(){ return a; }`, ¿no es así? Sé que no es lo mejor, pero por que quede más claro. Igualmente, muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ha aclarado muchas cosas :D

Comment: @DanoloAlcNom Si devuelves `A` creas una copia de tu objeto interno y los cambios que se hagan en la copia no afectan a tu objeto interno. Si, en cambio, devuelves `A&` entonces será el usuario de la función el que decida si quiere quedarse con una copia o con una referencia. Si elige la referencia podrá modificar tu objeto interno sin tu permiso, sin tu conocimiento y sin que tú puedas validar que el nuevo valor es válido.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la ayuda :)